# JPA Cascade a abstract/inherit Class on Delete

Tags: java, mysql, database, jpa, eclipselink

I have an abstract class `TreeNode`. From him i inherit the classes `Country` and `Location`. Then I have a class `Role` that includes predefined roles like administrator, user etc. These two classes are mapped together in the `MappedRole` class. The database table of mappedRole has columns treenode_id role_id und mappedRole_id.
The tables in the database look alike I have a table for country and location because I create Treenode with `Table_per_Class`. Therefore the table MappedRole has no ForeignKey for country and location.The treenode_id column in mappedRole contains then the id of the class its mapped to. JPA gets the relation with a big join on both tables.

This is my MappedRole Class:

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "TREENODE_ID", "ROLE_ID" }) }, name = "mappedrole")
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "mappedRole.checkIfUserExist", query = "SELECT count(mr.role) FROM MappedRole mr WHERE mr.role =?1") })
public class MappedRole implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TREENODE_ID", nullable = false)
    private TreeNode treeNode;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.REFRESH }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private Role role;
```

TreeNode class:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class TreeNode extends Observable {
        @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected long id;
```

and the location class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "standort")
@NamedQuery(name = "standort.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Standort s order by s.name desc")
public class Standort extends TreeNode implements Comparable<Standort>, Serializable {
```

If I now delete a location the mappedRole will not be deleted even though I have `CascadeType.REMOVE`. How can i make jpa cascade the delete operation of a location to the mappedRole table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cascading only works for the entity it is declared in. I.e.,

```
public class MappedRole {

  @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "TREENODE_ID", nullable = false)
  private TreeNode treeNode;
```

Should delete all corresponding `TreeNode`s *if and when* a `MappedRole` is deleted.

You don't seem to have the inverse `@OneToMany` relationship in `TreeNode` or `Standort`, so when you delete a `TreeNode` or `Standort` there's no relation on which JPA could cascade anything.

Try it like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class TreeNode ... {

  @OneToMany(cascade= { CascadeType.REMOVE }, mappedBy="treeNode" )
  private List<MappedRole> mappedRoles;
```

and make sure to put each `MappedRole` also into the `mappedRoles` list of it's owning `TreeNode`.

Comment: Thank you. But is the Annotation @MappedSuperclass important?

Comment: It's not relevant to your question, but I think it's better, if not required by the JPA standard, that *every* persistent class is annotated `@Entity`, `@Embeddable` or `@MappedSuperclass`.